# Java Errors: method cannot be applied to given types, inference variable has incompatible bounds

Tags: java, testing, driver, comparator, raw-types

While working on implementing the Merge Sort method in Java in a `Sorting.java` file, as part of an assignment, I am attempting to test my code with a separate `Driver.java` file.

Here is the header of the `mergeSort()` method in the `Sorting.java` file:

```
public class Sorting {
    public static <T> void mergeSort(T[] arr, Comparator<T> comparator) {
    }
}
```

Then, here is how I am trying to test it in the `Driver.java` file:

```
public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] testMergeSort1 = { 9, 13, 5, 6, 12, 10, 3, 7, 2, 8, 0, 15, 1, 4, 14, 11 };
        Sorting.mergeSort(testMergeSort1, new IntegerComparator());
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(testMergeSort1));
    }

    public class IntegerComparator implements Comparator<Integer> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Integer a, Integer b) {
            return a.intValue() - b.intValue();
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the errors that compiling the file generates:

```
Driver.java:29: error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
        Sorting.mergeSort(testMergeSort1, new IntegerComparator());
                                          ^
Driver.java:29: error: method mergeSort in class Sorting cannot be applied to given types;
        Sorting.mergeSort(testMergeSort1, new IntegerComparator());
               ^
  required: T[],Comparator<T>
  found:    int[],Driver.IntegerComparator
  reason: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
    equality constraints: Integer,int
    lower bounds: Object
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>mergeSort(T[],Comparator<T>)
```

Trying `Sorting.mergeSort(testMergeSort1, new IntegerComparator);` instead of `Sorting.mergeSort(testMergeSort1, new IntegerComparator());` generates the following error:

```
error: '(' or '[' expected
        Sorting.mergeSort(testMergeSort1, new IntegerComparator;
```

Any guidance understanding what the issue is and how to move towards resolving it would be appreciated.

Comment: `testMergeSort1` should be a `Integer[]`, not a `int[]`.

Comment: @Sweeper great catch, thank you very much. This now gives me the following error: `non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context`. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: `IntegerComparator` should also be `static` ... otherwise it is an inner class and requires  an enclosing instance (class `Driver`)

Comment: Change to :  public **static** class IntegerComparator

Comment: @user16320675 correct, the file is now compiling. Feel free to submit as an answer, so I can accept it.